# How to isolate coefficiets from complex fourier series?

Tags: fourier

[image]
[image]

I have to find yn/xn ratio.

From the circuit analysis i found out transfer function Uout//Uin =[image] . I am having hard time trying to isolate two coefficients of two complex fourier Series. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: One of your images say \$\hat{y}_n = \frac{\hat{x}_n}{1+jn\omega_0 R C}\$. Doesn't that already give you the ratio \$\frac{\hat{y}_n}{\hat{x}_n}\$ ?

Comment: thats what answer should be

Comment: Since you are referring to a transfer function, I assume the circuit is a *linear time invariant system*. Then, it has the property that the output for the sum of a set of signals is same as the sum of the outputs of the individual signals. Your `U_in` is the sum of certain signals. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LTI systems, use the linearity property.
$$
\begin{align}
H(s) \cdot \left(\sum X_i (s)\right) \mapsto{} & \sum H(s)\cdot X_i (s)
& {}={} &
\sum Y_i(s)
\\
h(t) \circledast \cdot \left(\sum x_i (t)\right) \mapsto{} & \sum h(t)\circledast x_i (t) 
& {}={} &
\sum y_i(t)
\end{align}
$$

From the above, \$\frac{y_i}{x_i}\$ or \$\frac{Y_i}{X_i}\$ can be found by comparing like terms.